# How to inject mobx store into a stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am using `mobx` and `react` in a web application and I want to find a way to pass `mobx` store state to a stateless component. Below is my current component source code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Panel from './Panel';
import {inject, observer} from 'mobx-react';

@inject(allStores => ({
  form: allStores.store.form,
}))
@observer
export default class Creator extends React.Component {

  connect() {
    console.log(this.props.form);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Panel form={this.props.form} connect={this.connect.bind(this)}/>
    );
  }
};
```

How can I change it to be stateless? I tried below code but didn't work:

```
const Creator = ({form}) => {

  const connect = ()=>{
    console.log('xxxx,', form);
  }

  return (
    <Panel form={form} connect={connect}/>
  );
}

export default observer(Creator);
```

when I run above code, I got `undefined` value for `form` on the `connect` method. How can I inject the store into stateless component? I tried to use `@inject` on top of stateless component, but got a syntax error.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`inject` returns a function that you can use on a observer functional component:

```
var Example = inject("myStore")(observer((props) => {
  // ...
}));
```

Comment: Is `"myStore"` actually an instance the store you want to inject?  I'm guessing it is.  And where does inject come from?  Is it mobx or mobx-react-lite?  When I search for it I get a page https://mobx-react.js.org/recipes-inject that says this site is DEPRECATED.  What version of MobX does this answer apply to?

Comment: @PatS You can inject any value, but most likely you will be injecting an instance of a store, yes. It's part of the [mobx-react](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#provider-and-inject) package. The documentation says "usually there is no need anymore to use `Provider` / `inject` in new code bases; most of its features are now covered by `React.createContext`."

Answer (score 8):

A variant of @Tholle answer :

```
const Example = inject("myStore")(observer(({myStore, otherProp}) => {
  // ...
}));
```

Comment: says it's not a function when you try to use it

Answer (score 2):

```
const Example = inject(
  'YOUR_STORE1',
  'YOUR_STORE2'
)(
  observer(({ YOUR_STORE1, YOUR_STORE2, OTHER_PROPS }) => {
    return (
        // Your Design
    )
  })
)

export default Example
```

Comment: Thx for sharing how to inject multiple stores at once!